# What is this pointer in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I have seen a lot of these types, but i have no idea what it means

```
unsigned char somevar[MAXLEN];
int *ptr = (int *) somevar;
```

Can someone explain?

Comment: This code is invalid C and will not do what the author expects it to do. Don't copy it.

Comment: @R..: Huh? This is valid and has well-defined behavior. Why not?

Comment: An arbitrary pointer of type `char *` does not necessarily meet the alignment requirements for an `int`, and may not be able to be faithfully stored in an `int *` (which may have fewer bits than `char *`). Even if the `int *` can store the value, if the alignment requirements are not met, the behavior is undefined when you try to dereference the pointer. Finally, there are aliasing considerations, which are mostly alleviated by the fact that one of the types involved is `char`.

Comment: @R.. I can't be 100% sure about C, since I haven't read the standard, unfortunately, but in C++ all your arguments are taken care of...

Comment: Nope, they're not. The code is equally invalid in C++. Making it valid would turn a single-opcode dereference into 15+ lines of asm on *every pointer dereference* on many archs. C++ may have a reputation for bloat and slowness but it's not *that* bad.

Comment: @R.. This is valid in C++, because: 1) a char,unsigned char, or signed char array is guaranteed to be properly aligned for any type (otherwise vector allocators would be really tough to implement :)). 2) int* may ***not*** have fewer bits than char*. I din't knowe what aliasing is though

Comment: @Armen: Only dynamically allocated arrays using `new char[]` are guaranteed that way. Stack or member variables do not have any such guarantees. There's a reason that there is a `std::aligned_storage<T>` in C++0x.

Comment: @DeadMG, @R.. Yes, you're right, I consulted the guys in the chat and the standard :)

Comment: Hmm, is this safe if you can verify that int * and char * are the same size and that int is divisible by char? I can see why someone would want to do this. EDIT: you'd also have to check endien..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just that `somevar` will be interpreted as a sequence of `int`'s (or just one) through the `ptr` pointer. Incrementing `ptr` just once moves the pointer `sizeof(int)` bytes ahead.

Be aware of endianness when doing conversions like these. The bytes from `somevar` may need reordering to be properly interpreted as ints.

Also make sure that `somevar` is of a length that's a multiple of `sizeof(int)`, otherwise you would get undefined behaviour when trying to access the last `int` since it will be partially available.

Comment: Further in the program where this piece of code is, there is a bswap32 function that swaps the endiannes.
Mersi mnogo.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially you're interpreting an array of chars as a pointer to int. Suppose `sizeof (int)` is 4 and the char array contains these bytes:

```
b0 b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7
```

Now `ptr` will point to `b0` but threat it as an `int`. That is,

`ptr[0]` is the integer comprised of bytes `b0, b1, b2, and b3`
`ptr[1]` is the integer comprised of bytes `b4, b5, b6, and b7`

HTH

Answer (score 0):

The identifier of an array in C is a pointer to the array's first element. So, in your example, somevar is an unsigned char * pointing to the first element of the array declared in the first line of the snippet.

And so it is then quite clear that ptr is also a pointer to the first element of the array, but thanks to the typecast it views it as a signed integer instead.

That's not necessarily a good typecast, there's a good chance that ints and chars are a completely different size and this could lead to some undefined behaviour.

Comment: Array's name is not a pointer. It can implicitly be converted to a pointer, but it is not a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This is often done when you read some raw bytes from, say, a binary file or off a network socket, and you know (from the data format or protocol) that these sequence of bytes represent an integer. This would give you a pointer that you can dereference and get the integer value represented by those bytes.

Answer (score 0):

On the right hand side it is a pointer to an int.

On the left hand side it is a variable (somevar) of unknown type being cast into a pointer to an int.  One would be well advised to look at somevar with a critical eye.  Sometimes casting in C is needed; but, more often casting in C in an indication that the wrong type for somevar was chosen or that you're doing something that is not likely to be portable.

In this case, you are packing chars into ints.  Depending on the system, you may arrive at an int with the internal bit representation which matches [char0, char1, char2, char3] followed by another int with the internal bit representation that matches chars four through seven.

However, on some other systems, you might arrive with an int with the internal bit representation of [char3, char2, char1, char0].  Finally there are other systems which handle bit order even more differently.

Odds are good that if you dig through the code enough, you'll find that there is another place where the pointer to your "constructed" int gets cast back into a char*.

Answer (score 0):

It is a pointer to the first value of the array. Since It is an unsigned char it would need to be type cast as int(well it does not need to be but it is good practice). As per someone concern over size a size int will for the most part always be smaller than an unsigned char.